# Shh! I'm supposed to be incognito

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My name is heard from the beginning of time.
>   Where to search for me?
>   Well, you can find me when you log in, watch closely.
>   I am original, indeed;
>   my reflection is seen in the night light.
>   Obtained by mixing ingredients, all the engineers need me...
>   Although you will not find any traces of me in a cup of coffee!

What am I?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> "gin"

My name is heard from the beginning of time.

> be**gin**ning of time

Where to search for me?
Well, you can find me when you log in, watch closely.

> you can find it quite easily when you lo**g in**

I am original, indeed;

> I am ori**gin**al

my reflection is seen in the night light.

> **nig**ht light has gin backwards, its "reflection"

Obtained by mixing ingredients, all the engineers need me...

> Mix**ing** **ing**redients, en**gin**eers, both contain "gin"

Although you will not find any traces of me in a cup of coffee!

> There is no "g", "i" or "n" in a cup of coffee.
>  and unless you spike it, a cup of coffee shouldn't have gin in it :P

As for the title:

> Shh! I'm supposed to be inco**gni**to

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49617/discussion-on-answer-by-dcfyj-shh-im-supposed-to-be-incognito).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Two posts in a couple minutes are not an extended discussion.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Sorry, boilerplate message; I should have edited it.  dcfyj asked that I move it to chat, because it was becoming conversational.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. :)

Comment: also "I am ori**gin**al".